# How to get ALT+B and ALT+L to work in the terminal?

Tags: unity, 12.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, keyboard-accelerators

I'm used to the terminal hot-keys <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to move forward one word and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to move back one word. However, in the new Unity of Ubuntu 12.04, this doesn't seem to work as holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and pressing <kbd>B</kbd> instead open the Help menu.

I have been looking around, but to no avail. I was wondering if anyone else has this issue as well?

Comment: if you switch to terminator it will work, not a solution but a workaround

Comment: Hi, I think you mean terminal right? Yes, if I switch to terminal, it'll work. Thanks :)

Comment: @- Vern no i meant terminator, but great that that worked to. @Jacob i do not believe  that a work around is an acceptable answer, thats why i made a comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much plowing around for about a day or so, I've finally found a solution to the question. Here's how to use the key combinations:

Hold down the <kbd>Super</kbd> Key (on most PC systems, this is what is known as the 'windows' key) and then use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

This is the way it is designed to work in Ubuntu 12.04.

Cheers, Vern

Answer (score 11):

There's another way around this: you have to turn off "Menu Access Keys".

Open the terminal window, go to "edit->keyboard shortcuts" and unselect the first check box "Enable menu access keys (Such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the File menu)".

After you unselect this, close and reopen Terminal and you should be able to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to move by word.